# How can I re-normalise the results of a de-normalised SQL statement?

Tags: java, sql, denormalization

I have a requirement to re-normalise the results of a de-normalised query into a class hierarchy.

This is not something I can use JPA for because the query is complex and requires Oracle specific functionality, such as query hints, window functions, and more.

I have provided a massively simplified example but in reality there will be many more tables and fields involved.

```
SELECT e.id,
       e.name,
       c.id,
       c.name
FROM      employee e
LEFT JOIN car      c ON e.id = c.employee_id;
```

---

```
|1|Robert Martin|1|BMW     |
|1|Robert Martin|2|Mercedes|
|2|Joshua Bloch |3|Lexus   |
|2|Joshua Bloch |4|Audi    |
```

I want to re-normalise the table above, which the persistence layer (querydsl-sql in this case) will return as a `List<Tuple>` into the structure below.

```
public class Employee {
    private final long id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<Car> cars;
}

public class Car {
    private final long id;
    private final String name;
}
```

The simplest way I can think to do this, is to process the data in the service layer, separating the fields for each entity and getting the distinct ones based on primary key - I was going to use the Java 8 streams API.

However, this feels like a lot of brittle, repetitive code / unit tests to write and maintain and comes across as a problem that must have been solved many times.

Is there a best practice method of achieving this goal, or perhaps some popular frameworks around that offer this kind of thing out-the-box?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

**EDIT:**
Failing any better ideas, I went ahead and used the Java 8 Streams API to re-normalise, leveraging `map` and `Collectors.groupingBy`. The code was easy to write, reads well and is easy to test.